# Get older visual studio command prompts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I try to build openCV,VTK,Qt,PCL and their dependencies on Windows10 x64. This was pretty doable for me on Ubuntu, but my first tries failed using minGW64, however, using MSVC compiler seems more promising.

Now I installed VS2022 and hoped that I could also use VS2019 or VS2017 compilers, because 2022 is not yet mentioned on the projects. What do I have to install that all the 2019 command prompts show up in windows start menu like they already do for VS 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install each version of Visual Studio side by side, 2015, 2017, 2019, 2022.

For each install you can choose the platform you need (native or Net) and de-select the other one along with things like web design.  You can also do this after installing by modifying the installation.

Once that is done, just go to the folder for each visual studio in the left side list of all programs, then pin each one's command prompt to start.